# How to get a type with multiple generic types to match the type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

For example, say I want a `Map<Class<?>, List<?>>`, so I can put in a class and get out a list of that type - is there something I can replace the question marks with to make that happen?

Comment: When you say "a list of that type", do you mean that the list elements are of the same type as the class?

Comment: It is unclear what you're usking.

Comment: its absolutely clear, OP wants to save a list of birds with the Bird.class key and list of cats with the Cat.class key

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Not that clear to me.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. @AdamSkywalker has it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the trick if you delegate type check to the method:

```
private class TypedMap {
    private Map<Class<?>, List<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void put(Class<T> key, List<T> value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    @SupressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> List<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (List<T>) map.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

- Wildcard `?` in map declaration does not ensure that key `Class<?>` and value `List<?>` would be of the same type. Method `put()` ensures that. You can not declare map as `Map<Class<T>, List<T>>` if your class is not generic - that's why you have to use a method.
- Get method is unchecked. The cast is safe if entries are added with `put()` method. (There's still a problem with raw types - but this is unavoidable)
- You can add more methods to TypedMap class, but remember about this restrictions.

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TypedMap map = new TypedMap();
    List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
    adder.put(Cat.class, cats);
    adder.put(Dog.class, dogs);

    adder.put(Cat.class, dogs); // compilation error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't completely enforce this, but one way to at least get a warning about it, is by using encapsulation:

```
public class MyClass {
    // private, private, private
    private Map<Class<?>, List<?>> myMap;

    public <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, List<T> list) { // both must have the same T.
        myMap.put(clazz, list);
    }
    ...
}
```

---

You can still break this by doing something like:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
Class c = Main.class;       
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();       
mc.put(c, l);
```

But you'll at least get a warning about unchecked conversion of `c` to `Class<String>`. And the unchecked invocation of `MyClass::put`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but `Map<Class<T>, List<T>>` would be the closest thing. The `T` is one single class type, though, so you can't put multiple classes into one `Map`.

You'll get a `ClassCastException` if you try to put objects of different classes into the same `Map`.