# Java: Working with Generics and Maps without Casting / @SuppressWarnings

Tags: java, generics, casting, pecs

I now came several times across this problem and always kinda solved this with some casts and `@SuppressWarnings` annotations.

### **The relevant interfaces / abstract classes:**

```
public abstract class Data { }

public interface DataOperations {
    boolean isValid();
}

public interface DataOperationsFactory<T extends Data> {
    Class<T> getDataClass();
    DataOperations getOperations(T data);
}
```

### **Example Implementations:**

```
public class DataImpl1 extends Data {
    public String foo;
}

public class DataImpl1Operations implements DataOperations {
    private DataImpl1 data;
    public DataImpl1Operations(DataImpl1 data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public boolean isValid() {
        return data.foo != null;
    }
}

public class DataImpl1OperationsFactory extends DataOperationsFactory<DataImpl1> {
    public Class<DataImpl1> getDataClass() {
        return DataImpl1.class;
    }
    DataOperations getOperations(DataImpl1 data) {
        return new DataImpl1Operations(data);
    }
}
```

Using this pattern, I can decide whether I need to create a `new DataImpl1Operations` everytime. Or maybe use a `final static NO_OP` implementation or what have you.

### **The Code:**

Now I'd like to put all those factories inside a `Map<Class<T>, DataOperationsFactory<T>>` (constructor). And afterwards read from it (`getOps` method).

```
public class Test {
    Map<Class<?>, DataOperationsFactory<?>> map;

    public Test(List<DataOperationsFactory<?>> fs) {
        for(DataOperationsFactory<?> f : fs) {
            map.put(f.getDataClass(), f);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends Data> DataOperations getOps(T data) {
        // --> Here I need to do an unchecked cast <--
        DataOperationsFactory<? super T> f =
                (DataOperationsFactory<? super T>) map.get(data.getClass());
        return f.getOperations(data);
    }
}
```

---

Is there any way doing this without unchecked casting?

Comment: Is ```DataOperations``` not supposed to be parametrized for the _type_ of ```Data```?

Comment: It doesn't have to, can be hard wired. I'll add some example implementation in a few minutes.

Comment: here's the same problem with wildcards in class members in different words  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865586

Comment: The thing that is bugging me is that both of the casts you show are invalid, because they are _too wide_ (although they end up working out any ways, since they are unchecked).

Comment: But these are the only casts where Eclipse doesn't output an error.

Comment: I'll make an edit to show what I mean, feel free to roll back afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delegate to a private method that captures the type, so it can be used to reliably cast to the correct Data subclass:

```
Map<Class<?>, DataOperationsFactory<?>> map;

// Unchanged
public Test(List<DataOperationsFactory<?>> fs) {
    for(DataOperationsFactory<?> f : fs) {
        map.put(f.getDataClass(), f);
    }
}

public DataOperations getOps(Data data) {
    DataOperationsFactory<?> f = map.get(data.getClass());
    return getOperations(f, data);
}

private static <T extends Data> DataOperations getOperations(DataOperationsFactory<T> f,
                                                             Data data) {
    return f.getOperations(f.getDataClass().cast(data));
}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! Still annoying that you've got to write extra code in order to fool the compiler for this to work without any warnings.